# Fill a column down, recursively applying a function to the previous value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

Consider this data

```r
data <- data.frame(
  group = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
  year = rep(2016:2025, 2),
  value = c(10, 20, 30, 40, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
            70, 80, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
data
#>    group year value
#> 1      A 2016    10
#> 2      A 2017    20
#> 3      A 2018    30
#> 4      A 2019    40
#> 5      A 2020    NA
#> 6      A 2021    NA
#> 7      A 2022    NA
#> 8      A 2023    NA
#> 9      A 2024    NA
#> 10     A 2025    NA
#> 11     B 2016    70
#> 12     B 2017    80
#> 13     B 2018    NA
#> 14     B 2019    NA
#> 15     B 2020    NA
#> 16     B 2021    NA
#> 17     B 2022    NA
#> 18     B 2023    NA
#> 19     B 2024    NA
#> 20     B 2025    NA
```

Now I’d like to fill in the missing values applying an arbitrary function
to the last non-missing value, recursively.

For example, let’s say that I want to
let the values increase by 10 points, yearly.

So, for rows where `value` is not NA, it should remain unmodified.
Starting from the row where `value` is NA, it applies that **value**<sub>**t**</sub> = **value**<sub>**t − 1**</sub> + **10**

A naive attempt to do it would be to use `dplyr::lag`,
but this only works for the first missing value because `lag` is vectorized and
operates on the `value` vector and do not recurse over the previous `value`s

```r
library(dplyr)
data |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  mutate(value_fix = dplyr::lag(value) + 10)   
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>    group  year value value_fix
#>    <chr> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 A      2016    10        NA
#>  2 A      2017    20        20
#>  3 A      2018    30        30
#>  4 A      2019    40        40
#>  5 A      2020    NA        50
#>  6 A      2021    NA        NA
#>  7 A      2022    NA        NA
#>  8 A      2023    NA        NA
#>  9 A      2024    NA        NA
#> 10 A      2025    NA        NA
#> 11 B      2016    70        NA
#> 12 B      2017    80        80
#> 13 B      2018    NA        90
#> 14 B      2019    NA        NA
#> 15 B      2020    NA        NA
#> 16 B      2021    NA        NA
#> 17 B      2022    NA        NA
#> 18 B      2023    NA        NA
#> 19 B      2024    NA        NA
#> 20 B      2025    NA        NA
```

This is where I thought `tidyr` could help, because it is somewhat similar
to tidyr::fill

```r
data |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  tidyr::fill(value)
```

but ideally, with an `.f` argument to be applied recursively to the last value.
There does not seem to be something like that.

Googling around I came up with this solution

```r
data |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  mutate(last_value = case_when(
    value == dplyr::last(na.omit(value)) ~ value,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  )) |> 
  mutate(value_fix = purrr::accumulate(
      .x = last_value,
      .f = ~ coalesce(.x + 10, .y)
  ))
#> # A tibble: 20 × 5
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>    group  year value last_value value_fix
#>    <chr> <int> <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 A      2016    10         NA        NA
#>  2 A      2017    20         NA        NA
#>  3 A      2018    30         NA        NA
#>  4 A      2019    40         40        40
#>  5 A      2020    NA         NA        50
#>  6 A      2021    NA         NA        60
#>  7 A      2022    NA         NA        70
#>  8 A      2023    NA         NA        80
#>  9 A      2024    NA         NA        90
#> 10 A      2025    NA         NA       100
#> 11 B      2016    70         NA        NA
#> 12 B      2017    80         80        80
#> 13 B      2018    NA         NA        90
#> 14 B      2019    NA         NA       100
#> 15 B      2020    NA         NA       110
#> 16 B      2021    NA         NA       120
#> 17 B      2022    NA         NA       130
#> 18 B      2023    NA         NA       140
#> 19 B      2024    NA         NA       150
#> 20 B      2025    NA         NA       160
```

Which works, but seems kind of hacky and not easy to read. It would be cleaner to just write the loop and be happy.

I really thought for such a simple case, there would be a built-in way (vectorized, readable-code) to do it in the tidyverse. But I could not find any. Am I missing something?, any ideas how to better do this?

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Have you tried na.locf function from zoo package?

Comment: Could you simplify what you have to something like: `data |> group_by(group) |> mutate(value_fix = accumulate(value, ~if(is.na(.y)) .x + 10 else .y))`?

Answer (score 2):

```
custom_fun <- function(x, y) {
  if(is.na(y)) x + 10 else y
}


data %>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(value = accumulate(value, custom_fun))

# Groups:   group [2]
   group  year value
   <chr> <int> <dbl>
 1 A      2016    10
 2 A      2017    20
 3 A      2018    30
 4 A      2019    40
 5 A      2020    50
 6 A      2021    60
 7 A      2022    70
 8 A      2023    80
 9 A      2024    90
10 A      2025   100
11 B      2016    70
12 B      2017    80
13 B      2018    90
14 B      2019   100
15 B      2020   110
16 B      2021   120
17 B      2022   130
18 B      2023   140
19 B      2024   150
20 B      2025   160
```

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution with `ave()` + `Reduce(accumulate = TRUE)`:

```r
transform(data, value = ave(value, group, FUN = \(val) {
    Reduce(\(x, y) if(is.na(y)) x + 10 else y, val, accumulate = TRUE)
}))

   group year value
1      A 2016    10
2      A 2017    20
3      A 2018    30
4      A 2019    40
5      A 2020    50
6      A 2021    60
7      A 2022    70
8      A 2023    80
9      A 2024    90
10     A 2025   100
11     B 2016    70
12     B 2017    80
13     B 2018    90
14     B 2019   100
15     B 2020   110
16     B 2021   120
17     B 2022   130
18     B 2023   140
19     B 2024   150
20     B 2025   160
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also write a vectorized function:

```
fun <- function(x){
  idx <- is.na(x)
  b <- rle(idx)
  id2 <- cumsum(b$lengths)[!b$values]
  x[idx] <- sequence(b$lengths[b$values], x[id2] + 10, by=10)
  x
}


transform(data, value = fun(value))

  group year value
1      A 2016    10
2      A 2017    20
3      A 2018    30
4      A 2019    40
5      A 2020    50
6      A 2021    60
7      A 2022    70
8      A 2023    80
9      A 2024    90
10     A 2025   100
11     B 2016    70
12     B 2017    80
13     B 2018    90
14     B 2019   100
15     B 2020   110
16     B 2021   120
17     B 2022   130
18     B 2023   140
19     B 2024   150
20     B 2025   160
```